# preg_replace replaces one extra character from the match

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a regex that almost works as it should :)

```
/test[^test<]/
```

I am using prep_replace() and I want it to find any occurrence of the string 'test' and replace it with test except one scenario when the string is 'test<' (means already replaced).

Test text is: 
"This is a test. Is this a test? some test and tests but test< testowanie"

It gives me this result:
"This is a test Is this a test some testand tests but test<
testwanie"

So it correctly excludes string 'test<' but with any other matches replaces 'test' + one extra character.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square brackets represent a character class, and the `^` represents negation of that character class. The end result is that you are matching the sequence `test` followed by any one character that is not `t`, `e`, `s`, `t` or `<`

Use this instead: `/test(?!<)/`, to match all occurrences of the sequence `test` not followed by left angle bracket.

Comment: That works! Thank you very much for your help. It was the first time when I have posted anything here and didn't expect such a quick response :)

Comment: Spoke too soon. I wasn't exactly right when posting this. Is it possible to modify this regex NOT to match any words that contain substring 'test' and finish with a '<' ? Now I have a problem that I am replacing word 'testowanie' with '[tag]testowanie[tag] and again right after do another replacemet so I end up with [tag][tag]test[tag]owanie[tag] ? Thanks

Comment: Just needed to add a word boundary \b to be /test(?!<)\b/. Now it works. Thanks again.